# Refreshing SpinButton SpinUp or SpinDown

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a spin button to my Excel spreadsheet so that when I click the spin button up my cell value increases by .01 and when I click the spin button down my cell value decreases by .01. I have the following code:

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()

Dim i As Integer

i = Sheet1.Range("E8").Value
Sheet1.Range("E8") = i + 0.01

End Sub
```

When I test the functionality of this code cell E8 goes up .01, but only once. When I click the button again, nothing happens. How can this be corrected?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change Integer to Double

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
Dim i As Double
i = Sheet1.Range("E8").Value
Sheet1.Range("E8") = i + 0.01

End Sub
```

Comment: I disagree - if you remove `Dim i As Integer` and it's still working then you've not got `Option Explicit` at the top of the module which can open a whole big can of worms.  Change `Integer` to `Double` as `Integer` will only accept whole numbers, while `Double` can work with fractions of a number.  Or, use the built in functionality of Spin buttons to change a cell value and divide the number by 100 in another cell to get the value you're after.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook is correct.  You should not let VB guess what your variables should be.  You are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3):

An integer will not store the decimal value.  So if you have 8 in cell E8 you are getting 8 in the int and then writing 8 + .01 to cell E8 so you get 8.01.

The next time you read 8.01 into the int, VB is rounding off the decimals so you are getting 8 in the int again and adding the same value back in.

You need to change the variable to decimal variable.

Taking out the variable declaration will just make VB guess what to use and that is not a good practice.  You should use "Option Explicit" at the top of your code to prevent this.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()

    Dim i As Double

    i = Sheet1.Range("E8").Value
    Sheet1.Range("E8") = i + 0.01

End Sub
```

You could also use

```
Dim i As Single
```

depending on the size of the decimal that it could get to.

Comment: @ManishChristian Hopefully the OP checks back and tries option explicit.  As you know, there are a lot of ways to make things work, but it doesn't mean they are correct.

Comment: I agree and that's the reason accepted answer have been edited ;)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to store the value in a variable. Try this.

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()

    Sheet1.Range("E8").Value = Sheet1.Range("E8").Value + 0.01

End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton2_SpinDown()

    Sheet1.Range("E8").Value = Sheet1.Range("E8").Value - 0.01

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, have voted down as have not dealt with the `Integer` problem.  Actually, re-reading it you have - could at least remove the declaration bit though  - will vote back up again if I can.  :)  lol, can vote up to 1 or down to -1, but can't change back to 0.